# How to only add a space only if middle name exist and a space only if suffix exist in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

I have 4 input fields for first, middle, last, and suffix with only first and last name required. I want to add a space after first name only if there is a middle name provided and only a comma after the last name if a suffix is provided.

```
Ex. 
Joe Smith -> "Joe Smith"
Joe Jon Smith -> "Joe Jon Smith"
Joe Smith Jr -> "Joe Smith, Jr"
Joe Jon Smith Jr -> "Joe Jon Smith, Jr"
```

Comment: If you need to do something depending on condition, you use `if`.  What seems to be the problem?

Comment: what have you tried? please show the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const formattedName = `${first}${middle ? ` ${middle}` : ''} ${last}${suffix ? `, ${suffix}` : ''}`
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could use regular expressions to remove consecutive spaces, and any trailing comma from the unspecified suffix.

```js
function formattedName(firstName = '', middleName = '', lastName = '', suffix = '') {
  return `${firstName} ${middleName} ${lastName}, ${suffix}`
    .replace(/\s+/, ' ')
    .replace(/, $/, '');
}

console.log(formattedName('John', '', 'Smith', ''));
console.log(formattedName('John', 'Jacob', 'Smith', ''));
console.log(formattedName('John', '', 'Smith', 'Jnr.'));
console.log(formattedName('John', 'Jacob', 'Smith', 'Jnr.'));
```